# Changing images and making those persist when the click on list view is released

Tags: android, onclick, android-listview, android-image

I have some number of rows in my list view and each row have two different images on list click event. When I click on a list view then I want to change the image of that list view. The image changes on the mouse click. But as soon as the click is released the image disappears. I want it to persist even when the click is released.

Below is the code I have used.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p, View view, int position,
                        long id) {

    listViewpos = position;
    listViewName = hospitalList.get(position).HospName;
    selectedHosp = WSParser.hospitalInfo.get(position);
    hospitalID = selectedHosp.HospID;
    Log.d("onCreate", "hospitalID " + hospitalID);
    vwSubParent = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
    vwChildLay = (LinearLayout) vwSubParent.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
    imgSelected = (ImageView) vwChildLay.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imgSelected.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listviewselectorimage);
}
```

The listviewselectorimage.xml is as given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- When selected, use selected mark -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selectedmark"
          android:state_pressed="true" />

    <!-- When not selected, use selectedmark_black-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selectedmark_black" />
</selector>
});
```